# How to generate event on button  proragmmatically to go next page  in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have created a button programmatically and I want to fire event to go next page, the event is not generated. What can I do?

This is the code:

```
btnSignUp =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnSignUp.frame =CGRectMake(20,250,280,35);
[btnSignUp setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSignUp addTarget:self action:@selector(registrationPage:)  
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents]; 

    -(void)registrationPage:(id)sender
    {           
    registration =[[RegistrationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done all grt work!! Just one line change..

btnSignUp =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

```
    btnSignUp.frame =CGRectMake(20,250,280,35);

    [btnSignUp setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnSignUp addTarget:self action:@selector(registrationPage:) 

forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];





-(void)registrationPage:(id)sender
{   

registration =[[RegistrationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];

}
```

This will definitely work for you

Comment: Look at my code__

RegistrationPage *r = [[RegistrationPage alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"RegistrationPage" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:r animated:YES];
  //error [r release];

It gives me error when i try to release resorce of r ! Can you give soltuion ?

Comment: i am not getting your issue properly??

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
[btnSignUp addTarget:self action:@selector(registrationPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//methodname
{
btnSignUp.frame =CGRectMake(20,250,280,35);
btnSignUp =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btnSignUp setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSignUp addTarget:self action:@selector(registrationPage)  
forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents]; 
}
-(void)registrationPage
{           
registration =[[RegistrationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Registration" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];
[registration release];
}
```